# In C# LINQ How to keep two separate lists or Data tables based on status data

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of `ListRecords`:

```
InCorrectNumber CorrectNumber   Status
---------------------------------------
10101010        7003594558      VALID
20202020        7003310682      VALID
2244448         2222222         INVALID
30303030        6130985705      VALID
3434448         1111111         INVALID
8273648         3333333         INVALID
```

Using Linq, how do I split the values from `ListRecords` list into 2 different lists?

For example:

ValidList1:

```
InCorrectNumber CorrectNumber   
------------------------------
10101010        7003594558  
20202020        7003310682  
30303030        6130985705
```

InValidValidList1:

```
InCorrectNumber CorrectNumber
------------------------------
2244448         2222222 
3434448         1111111 
8273648         3333333
```

I have tried as shown here - not sure, it's not working working with good performance

```
List<accounts> openEvents = ValidList1 .Where(e => e.Status == VALID);
List<accounts> closedEvents = InValidValidList1.Where(e => e.Status == INVALID);
```

Comment: Will be great if you can show your attempt

Comment: thanks for the response, this is my below code :- List<accounts> openEvents = ValidList1 .Where(e => e.Status == VALID);
List<accounts> closedEvents = InValidValidList1.Where(e => e.Status == INVALID);

Comment: Sidenote, "incorrect" and "invalid" are one word, so the third letter of each should not be capitalized (`IncorrectNumber` instead of `InCorrectNumber`).

Comment: If you done splitting data by status into different lists, I don't see any reason that you need to use the `.WHERE()` to filter data again. *its not working working with good performance*, this is hard to help you without provide more info such as how many records you are retrieved from DB, did your table create/use any index for `Status` column, consider to return the column that is required instead of returning all columns from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given these definitions:

```
public class Account
{
    public long IncorrectNumber;
    public long CorrectNumber;
    public Status Status;
}

public enum Status
{
    VALID, INVALID
}
```

And this data:

```
List<Account> ListRecords = new List<Account>()
{
    new Account { IncorrectNumber = 10101010L, CorrectNumber = 7003594558L, Status = Status.VALID },
    new Account { IncorrectNumber = 20202020L, CorrectNumber = 7003310682L, Status = Status.VALID },
    new Account { IncorrectNumber = 2244448L, CorrectNumber = 2222222L, Status = Status.INVALID },
    new Account { IncorrectNumber = 30303030L, CorrectNumber = 6130985705L, Status = Status.VALID },
    new Account { IncorrectNumber = 3434448L, CorrectNumber = 1111111L, Status = Status.INVALID },
    new Account { IncorrectNumber = 8273648L, CorrectNumber = 3333333L, Status = Status.INVALID },
};
```

Then using `ToLookup` is the way to go:

```
var lookup = ListRecords.ToLookup(x => x.Status);

List<Account> openEvents = lookup[Status.VALID].ToList();
List<Account> closedEvents = lookup[Status.INVALID].ToList();
```

That gives me:

[image: results]